# How to use ObjectAnimator for View property Y before sdk 14

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm trying to use ObjectAnimator to animate the "x" and "y" property of a view. It works great in api 14+, but I noticed that these properties were added to the view class in api 14. How do I get them to work pre api 14?
I've considered the following but am stuck:

```
            ObjectAnimator y = new ObjectAnimator();
            Property<View, Float> yProperty;
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){yProperty = Property.of(View.class, Float.class, "y");}
            else{yProperty = Property.of(View.class, Float.class, "top");}
            y.setProperty(yProperty);
```

Comment: Have you looked at nineoldandroid? It seems to support: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/blob/master/library/src/com/nineoldandroids/animation/ObjectAnimator.java